# How to get Audio path from listview

Tags: java, android

I am creating `mp3` player unable to get audio path `URI` using `media.uri.data` is not working please help me how get path audio file path?
Here is my code. I am searching lot but did not found the answer `media.uri.data` is return null what should do?I am unable stuck only in this step help?

```
 package com.monstertechno.musicplayerappui;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.renderscript.Sampler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;
import com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout;
import com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private ArrayList<Song> songList;
        private ListView songView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            runtimpermission();
            songView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);
            songList = new ArrayList<Song>();
            SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
            songView.setAdapter(songAdt);
            getSongList();
            Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
                public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
                    return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
                }
            });

            songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if(mediaPlayer!=null){
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                    }



                }
            });

        }




        public void  runtimpermission(){

            Dexter.withActivity(this)
                    .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

                    .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                        @Override public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permisson Access", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        @Override public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permisson Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                        @Override


                        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {


                            token.continuePermissionRequest();}
                    }).check();

        }

        public void getSongList() {
            //retrieve song info
            ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

            if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
                //get columns   
                int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                        (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

                //add songs to list
                do {
                    long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                    String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                    String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                    songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
                }
                while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: did you give it     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
This permission and make sure it is granted?Sorry didn't check your code. Just be sure it's granted?

Comment: yes i give external storage permission my problem is just getting audio path from listview

Comment: Well if you have filled your arrayList then just get the item you need?What's the problem?You said that "answer media.uri.data is return null ",so how did you fill your array so that now you want to get data from it?

Comment: Dear my all audio file show in list view successfully which present in my device but problem is that i am unable to play how can get path of specific audio file while i am  successful fetching audio title and album name

Answer (score 0):

Okay you were'nt clear enough,I add a complete code in case any body needs it you only need one line of it though:

```
Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, selection, null, sortOrder);
int count = 0;
if (cur != null) {
    count = cur.getCount();
    if (count > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String album = (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)));
            String artist = (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)));
            String title =(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
            String path = (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
            String alumbId =(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)));
            long duration = (cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)));
            Cursor cursorImage = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART}, MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(alumbId)}, null);
            assert cursorImage != null;
            if (cursorImage.moveToFirst()) {
                String imagePath = cursorImage.getString(cursorImage.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
            }
        }
    }
}
cur.close();
```

It works I just tested it.Just check for null for imagePath.